# Unable to call server side method in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working in asp.net. I have this HTML tag

HTML tag:

```
<button id="submit" class="button" onserverclick="delete_Click">Login</button>
```

Serverside Function:

```
 Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

When I click the button it should go to Login.aspx page. But button is not working. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: you set a break point in you server side delete_click button handler , and it is being hit for sure?

Comment: No its not. I have done it :(

Answer (score 3):

Use `OnClick` instead of `onserverclick` and better to use ASP.NET control if you are achieving this

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="delete_Click">Login</asp:Button>
```

Comment: I can only use HTML button tag. I did this but still not working
<button runat="server" id="submit" class="button" onclick="delete_Click">Login</button>

Comment: No if you are using HTML button tag then try with this `<button id="submit" class="button" runat="server" onserverclick="delete_Click">Login</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
runat="server"
```

to the html tag.

Also, you need to make use of the `OnClick` event handler.

In essence, you tag should look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" class="button" OnClick="delete_Click">Delete</asp:Button>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I can only use HTML button tag. I did this but still not working <button runat="server" id="submit" class="button" onclick="delete_Click">Login</button>